# matplotlib line with markers and line width - unexpected results

Tags: matplotlib

Seems like a super simple thing, hopefully I'm missing something obvious or there is a bug in matplotlib. I'm using matplotlib 1.4.3 if that helps.

```
from pylab import *
t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = sin(2 * pi * t)
plot(t, s, c='m', lw=10)
```

[image]

Everything looks good. Awesome.

```
from pylab import *
t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = sin(2 * pi * t)
plot(t, s, c='m', lw=10, marker='o', mfc='m')
```

[image]

Say what?? My line is now blue, even though I have c='m'??

Even more confusing ... don't set the line width...

```
from pylab import *
t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = sin(2 * pi * t)
plot(t, s, c='m', marker='o', mfc='m')
```

[image]

Again, works as expected, no problems, line color is magenta c='m'. What am I missing here? Why is the line color blue if I set a line width and have markers?

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 0):

Well, figured out one workaround, call plot twice. One with the marker and then again with the linewidth. Still seems like a matplotlib bug, but I'll wait to report anything in hopes someone here has a proper solution or answer to why it behaves this way.

```
from pylab import *
t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = sin(2 * pi * t)
plot(t, s, c='m', marker='o')
plot(t, s, c='m', lw=4)
```

[image]